# Filtrar por un campo especifico en sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo en mi base de datos varios campos con el mismo nombre pero cambian el numero,por ejemplo: campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4 y me gustaria filtrar por el campo cuyo numero sea el mayor, pero teniendo en cuenta que se pueden añadir mas campos con el mismo nombre(campo5,campo6). Hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin tener que cambiar el codigo constantemente?, es decir, que sql identifique que campo tiene el numero mayor.
Gracias!

Comment: En access?, prácticamente no se puede hacer. Esto requiere leer los nombres de las columnas, detectar los dígitos al final, convertirlos a número para ver el más grande, y luego usar una especie de SQL dinámico para leer esa columna en específico

Comment: Vale entiendo. Y si ese campo fuera el último que se añadiera?, es decir yo sé que el de mayor número va a ser el último campo que se añade(último campo de la tabla) hay alguna forma de filtrar por el último campo? Muchas gracias!

Comment: de todas formas requiere ejecutar cierto sql dinámico, lo que implicaría hacer algún código en VBA